# Sitecore FXM URL with multiple domains

Tags: fxm

We have a website that has multiple domains for each language. For example, we might have **example.com**, **example.ca**, **example.fr**, **child.example.ca**, etc. However, the issue we're running into is with subdomains such as **child.example.ca**. We would like the beacon URL to pull from **example.ca** however we have found that while we can update the beacon script injection to pull from **example.ca**, the tracking will fail with a `CORS missing allow permission` since the hostname for `SCBeacon` will read **example.com**.

To fix this, we tried removing our config values from `Sitecore.FXM.Config` for `FXM.Hostname`. The result has been inconsistent. Sometimes the beacon URL for **example.fr/bundle/beacon** will return **example.fr** and sometimes it will return **example.ca**.

We have also tried setting the **FXM.Hostname** parameter in each site's `SiteDefinition` config, but has the same result.

What are some possible solutions to this problem? We are on `Sitecore 9.2`

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this setting below with this config

`\App_Config\Sitecore\FederatedExperienceManager\Sitecore.FXM.config`:

```
  <!-- FXM BASE HOST DOMAIN
    When the Sitecore site and external sites are hosted on a common base domain but under different
    sub domains (and the sub domain isn't 'www'), then this setting should be set to the common base domain.  
    The following table best explains this:
    
    Site A                  Site B                    Base Host Domain
    shop.mysite.co.uk       jobs.mysite.co.uk         mysite.co.uk
    shop.mysite.co.uk       www.mysite.co.uk              -             (www is a special case and accounted for)
    www.mysite.co.uk        mysite.co.uk                  -
    shop.mysite.co.uk       mysite.co.uk                  -
    shop.mysite.co.uk       jobs.mysite.com               -
    mysite.co.uk            mysite.com                    -
  -->
  <setting name="FXM.BaseHostDomain" value="" />
```